# css hover div position auto left and right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a hover open div with css. I created it but i have one question about hover position left and right.

First of all sorry for my english.

I created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/JHuAg)** from Codepen.

My question is: If you check my demo page you see information and location icon. When you hover over information or location icon then you see bubble div. in the upper left corner of the nice parts. but if you hover over information or location on the right side then you see bubble carry out.

I don't want to carry out bubble. I want to make a bubble stay in main div inside. What should i do for this ? Anyone can help me here ?
Here is my HTML code:

```
 <div class="ssss">
      <div class="s_u_a">
        <div class="user_p_c_p">
          <img src="1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="user_p_p_p">
          <img src="2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="u_l_inf"> 
          <div class="u_l_"><div class="uynott">test</div></div>
          <div class="u_inf_"><div class="uynott2">test</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="u_p_n_">test</div>
        <div class="u_p_n_s">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

in this html code main div is `.sss`

and this is my css code for bubble:

```
.u_l_:hover .uynott {
 position:relative;
 opacity:1; 
   visibility:visible;


    transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
}
.uynott 
{
font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
position: relative;
width: 295px;
height: auto;
padding: 10px;
background-color:#5890ff;
color:#fff;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
border: #5890ff solid 1px;
visibility:hidden;
line-height: 21px;
margin-left: -25px;
  opacity:0;
  margin-top:25px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out; 
  z-index:5;
}

.uynott:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 8px 8px;
border-color: #5890ff transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: -8px;
left: 20px;
}

.uynott:before 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 8px 8px;
border-color: #5890ff transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
top: -9px;
left: 20px;
}

.u_inf_:hover .uynott2 {
 position:relative;
 opacity:1; 
   visibility:visible;


    transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
}
.uynott2 
{
font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
position: relative;
width: 295px;
height: auto;
padding: 10px;
background-color:#5890ff;
color:#fff;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
border: #5890ff solid 1px;
visibility:hidden;
line-height: 21px;
margin-left: -115px;
  opacity:0;
  margin-top:25px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out; 
  z-index:5;
}

.uynott2:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 8px 8px;
border-color: #5890ff transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: -8px;
left: 115px;
}

.uynott2:before 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 8px 8px;
border-color: #5890ff transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
top: -9px;
left: 115px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH... you just have to make another class for your divs at the right and move the div hidden before hover.

here you have your code working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bDrwk

```
code
```

Just have a look at the changes I made and you will easily see what you had to do. won't copy all the code as it will be as long as yours (even longer) and a bit confusing I move also the little arrow of your bubble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if you check your demo can you hover over the right side information icon because the arrow shows left user information.

Comment: Updated code... but mate... you could see how I fix one arrow so you fix yourself the other. I feel like I'm just working for You insteed of helping a doubt

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understand the problem. You are a a good instructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `width:295px` from the class `.uynott2` and check the output!!